# Dynamic paint not working

Tags: dynamic-paint

I'm making an animation of a stencil paint against a wall. I'm trying to resemble the graffiti painting whit dynamic paint over a logo. But I can't make it work. Assuming the issue was sited at the logo material, I tryied setting it to: 1 - transparent BSDF 2 - diffuse BSDF 3 - image texture. None of them gave me the key. Also tried applying or not dynamic paint on modifiers, and had no succes. When changing canvas mode from paint to wave, it worked. Might that give a clue?

This is my project: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48XSxEO28GMNTZaSHBmUTlETEhKWTFtSV9Ga21kQm50cWZZ/view?usp=drivesdk

This is a closely related question I made about the same project: [Spray paint simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108596/54157)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spray paint simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108596/spray-paint-simulation)

Comment: how is this different then your other question?

Comment: In this question, I'm talking about the animation of the wall receiving paint. The other question asks about the paint flying through the air, emmited from the spray can.