# Blender Fluid Simulation Inflow From Particle System With Liquid Simulation

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I can't figure out how to make liquid inflow come from the particle system. I know smoke and fire simulation can use particle systems. So how can I make particle systems work with liquid simulation? Or how could I make spray effect some other way?

Link to example project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mi1Cn4jw-h5rlnegF6LBxAVLh3T7ydUr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think there is such thing possible (use particle system as inflow source). To the second part of your question - Can you add some reference (image, animGIF) what do you want to achieve?

Comment: For spray effect (like color in bottle pushed by glass pressure, used by street artists) use can use particle system with Dynamic Paint. Not the best example with smoke, but you can get idea https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108596/spray-paint-gas-simulation

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this could be the use of dupliverts, which gives 99,99% of the particle system effect. The difference can be found in the Blender manual. And if you want to model a shower you can punch holes in a cylinder's bottom, make it an obstacle and put the inflow inside.